# Does chef overwrite file owners when deploying? Can it be avoided?

Tags: deployment, chef-infra, devops

I have a chef cookbook for deploying our webapp, there are some folders and files that need to be created and owned by `www-data:www-data`. When deploying the application I'm doing it by using the chef's `deploy` command like this in my `deploy.rb` recipe:

```
deploy "#{app_dir}" do
  repository tmp_dir
  user "root"
  group "root"
  environment app[:environment]
  symlink_before_migrate({})
end
```

And then the creation and permission set for those files and folders are done in the `before_symlink.rb` script like this:

```
execute "ensure correct owner of storage folder" do
  command "chown -R www-data:www-data #{release_path}/storage"
end
```

I've been debugging and I've checked this:

1. `chown` is executed, and the user exists, I can see it in the chef logs.
2. If I execute a `sleep` command right at the end of the before_symlink and then ssh into the machine I can see in the `storage` folder that the folder is owned by `www-data` as I wish.
3. If I execute a `sleep` command right after the deploy command on `deploy.rb` and then ssh to the machine, now the release folder will be linked to the `current` folder, and every file and folder will be owned by `root:root` causing permission errors.

So it seems that at the end of the deploy chef seems to overwrite the owner for every deployed file to the user making the deploy. Is this true? Is there any way to keep files and folders with the owner set on `before_symlink.rb`?

Comment: If the owner/group is `www-data:www-data` why do you assign the resource to `root:root`?
Set the correct one directly in the `deploy` resource.

Answer (score 0):

Really *really* don't use the deploy resource. What you want is probably a `git` resource, and its `user` property.